# vertices and edges on a cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Show that if a simple graph with at least two vertices is connected and has no cut vertices, then any two vertices lie on a cycle and any two edges lie on a cycle.

I assume if $G$ is connected and has no cut vertices, then if we remove any vertex from $G$, the remaining graph is still connected. And does that automatically mean any two vertices lie on a cycle and any two edges lie on a cycle?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @jwc845 So I assume if $G$ is connected and has no cut vertices, then if we remove any vertex from $G$, the remaining graph is still connected. And does that automatically mean any two vertices lie on a cycle and any two edges lie on a cycle?

Comment: This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005438/show-any-two-edges-in-a-2-connected-graph-lie-on-a-cycle/